# Get image via https and php

Tags: php, image, https

Hy!

I'm trying to get an image per https in php.

What I've found is something like this code which shows me an **blank** image with correct width but wrong height:

```
    function getSslPage($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }

    echo getSslPage("https://www...");
```

I'm grateful for any help. :)

Comment: Use `curl_error()` to see what goes wrong

Comment: `curl` does NOT modify image dimensions, it's probably something related to image!

Comment: You almost certainly have something being output other than just the image data (for example a PHP error message or leading whitespace before the opening `<?php` tag). Also note that there's no reason to `return` the image data and echo it if that's all you are doing, you can simply not bother with the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, which will be more resource efficient.

Comment: sorry .. I'm new to php and web developing ..
When I try "echo curl_error ($ch);" to get some error message, so I did became nothing.

Comment: Can someone tell me the correct way to display an image via https?
Explain it please so, that a noob like me can understand it. ;)

Comment: @RobertJaskowski No need to apologize :-) Can you elaborate on your last comment? I don't quite get what you are saying - do you get an error message or not?

Comment: I don't get any error message :(
I've put the code (curl_error($ch)) before curl_close($ch) ..

Comment: @RobertJaskowski Check to see if there is any other output created by your script. Comment out the `return $result;` and see if you get anything (including whitespace) from your script.

Comment: When I comment out the return $result; so I get just a small icon for a blank image - without specific widht or height - just 16x16 pixel.
No whitespacec or anything like this.

EDIT: but only when I've added the new code "$ctype="image/png";
header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);" from Yatin Trivedi.
Without his code snippet I get nothing - no whitespace or anything.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it in any situation:

```
$ch = curl_init ($source_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$fp = fopen($local_file,'w');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work,

try to run this code,

```
function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
$ctype="image/png";
header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

echo getSslPage("https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/services/mail/phone.png");
```