# Get image with curl via https

Tags: php, image, curl, https

I have script which gets image from http and it works fine, but when I try to get image from https link it is not working. I am using curl, and I have found this [Get image via https and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574671/get-image-via-https-and-php) but it is not working.

**My code:**

```
    $image_url="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/services/mail/phone.png";
$slika = getSslPage($image_url);
if(!empty($slika))
    file_put_contents('vest.jpg', $slika);

function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

phpinfo is giving me this information

```
Protocols: dict, file, ftp, gopher, http, imap, pop3, rtsp, smtp, telnet, tftp
```

and command line is showing https

```
root@server [~]# curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
```

Comment: Your script works fine on my server.
I believe it's a configuration issue of your php installation.
Maybe try debug more deeply, using `curl_error`

Comment: it is working on my server if I am using picture from http, but it I am using from https like in that sample it is not. Please give me more information

Comment: Does the source have a SSL channel? Can you reach the image in your browser that way?

Comment: use curl_error to get more information!!

Comment: I have received error "Curl error: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl "

Comment: phpinfo is giving me this information
"Protocols: dict, file, ftp, gopher, http, imap, pop3, rtsp, smtp, telnet, tftp", 
and command line is showing 
root@server [~]# curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by installing curl ssl

```
/scripts/easyapache
option 7 on the menu
select PHP
scroll down and select CURL with SSL
exit
save
```

Everything is working now